# Store character array buffer as hex in a uint32_t buffer in C

Tags: c

I'm able to read a hex file and store the content in a char buffer, i need to store  the character in char buffer as hex value in a buffer as shown below. so that i can use that hex value to write into a hardware data register which accepts `uint32_t` only.

```
char * buffer =[AABBCCDDEE112233445566]
```

output:

> partitioned_buffer= 0xAABBCCDD
>
> partitioned_buffer= 0xEE112233

and so on. Can any one help on this. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *fip_buffer;
char *emmc_pattern_buffer;

char hex_pattern() { 
    FILE *fileptr;
    char *buffer;
    long filelen;
    int i,j;
    

    fileptr = fopen("fip.hex", "rb");         
    if( fileptr == NULL ) {
       printf("cannot open file");// exit(1);
     }
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);          
    filelen = ftell(fileptr);            
    rewind(fileptr);                      
    fip_buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); 

    for(i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
       fread(fip_buffer+i, 1, 1, fileptr); 
    
    }
       
    
    fclose(fileptr); // Close the file
    return(fip_buffer);
}



char hex_pattern_read(int a, int filelen){
char mem[8],mem2[7];
int i,j;
for(i=a;i<filelen;i++){
      mem[j]=fip_buffer[i];
      mem[8]='\0';
      j++;
      if(j==8){strcpy(mem2,mem);j=0; break;
       }
   } 
   emmc_pattern_buffer=mem2;
   return(emmc_pattern_buffer);
}




int main(int argc, char **argv) {
printf("Reading hex file\n");
int i,j;
hex_pattern();
int len = strlen(fip_buffer);
//printf("size of buffer is=%d\n%c\n",len,fip_buffer);
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
  // printf("Entered loop1");
 for(j=0;j<3;j++){
   int temp = (j*8)+(128*i);
    hex_pattern_read(temp,len); //need to store the returned emmc_pattern_buffer character as hex value 
   printf("%02X\n",emmc_pattern_buffer);
  }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: The `char * buffer =[AABBCCDDEE112233445566]` does not compile on my compiler. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I'm not sure what "partitioned character" is supposed to mean.  Are you just trying to say that you want to pack four input bytes into one `uint32_t`?

Comment: the first character is 0xA or 0xAA?

Comment: Also, by "hex" do you mean "binary"? I take the former to mean that the data consist of ASCII characters '0' ... '9', 'A' ... 'F', each representing four bits.  This is of course a common way for humans to describe the data content to a computer (e.g. in source code) and for computers to represent it to humans (e.g. in printed messages and data dumps), but it is quite rare for this to be the machine representation of the data.

Comment: I just gave a example of char * buffer =[AABBCCDDEE112233445566], actually im reading the hex file content into a buffer, and the buffer has series of characters in it as 12345678aa64000101681fa1ed19f39d41e... and so, and im trying to read 8 character each time and im able to print them, but i want to store that character to hex values.

Comment: I'm confused now, file content is in `hex`. and where and why you want to store it back in `hex`?

Comment: I do not know what an hex file is. I know what could be a *binary* file for which first *bytes* would be 0xAA, 0xBB, etc., and I know what could be a *text* file for which the first characters would be AABB... (assuming ASCII that would be bytes 0x41, 0x41, 0x42, 0x42, etc.). Which one is yours?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I believe the OP is referring to an "Intel Hex" file. In this case the data is stored as text with multiple fields per line giving the address offset, type etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: after better reading all comments, I think that even if the file is not a true Intel Hex file, it is a text file containing hex representation of bytes. Still not sure about endianness. Saying differently should the sequence `12345678` give `0x12345678` (ala big endian) of `0x78563412` (ala little endian)?

Answer (score 1):

From comments ...

> im reading the hex file content into a buffer, and the buffer has
>   series of characters in it as 12345678aa64000101681fa1ed19f39d41e...
>   and so, and im trying to read 8 character each time and im able to
>   print them, but i want to store that character to hex values.

... I understand that you are successfully reading the hexadecimal *text* representation of a 32-bit unsigned number from your input file, and you want to convert that to the machine's internal numeric representation.  For this purpose, it makes no difference at all whether the bytes have have separate individual significance.

The easiest way to accomplish the task, then, is to make your buffer at least nine bytes long, so that it has room for eight hexadecimal digits plus a string terminator, ensure the terminator is present, and use the `strtoul()` function to perform the conversion:

```
char buffer[9];
// ... fill buffer, including terminator byte ...
char *end;
uint32_t value = strtoul(buffer, &end, 16);
if (end != buffer + 8) // ... handle bad data ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, There is a file with byte stream which has to be sent to `register` by packing 4bytes each.

You can combine individual bytes to make `uint32_t` as follows,

```
uint32_t partitioned_buffer =  (buffer[0]<<24u) | (buffer [1]<<16u) | (buffer[2]<<8u) |  buffer[3];
```

You can even convert byte stream into o/p `uint32_t` buffer as follows,

```
uint32_t partitioned_buffer[op_bufferSize];
for(i =0;i<op_bufferSize;i++)
 {
     int offset = i<<2;
    partitioned_buffer[i] =  (buffer[offset+0]<<24u) | (buffer [offset+1 ]<<16u) | (buffer[offset+2]<<8u) |  buffer[offset+3];
 }
```

Comment: Hi TruthSeeker, No, my question is, im already able to read 8 characters i.e(AABBCCDD) and print them, but i need to save the characters to hex format i.e (0xAABBCCDD)

Comment: @ranjitham : Let me rephrase my understanding, I tried to understand your code. You want to print hexadecimal value of your file with 8byte on each line. Something like [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkMMSl5xL) or  [this](https://onlinegdb.com/rJlI4dg5xI)

Comment: No, im able to read and print as a character, but i need to save the character as same hex value. for ex: im reading ABCDABCD as a character, i need to save this as hex value i.e 0xABCDABCD

Comment: @ranjitham: where you want to store the hex value? If u can get individual `char` then what's stopping you from converting it to hex? Mapping of each `char` to hex equivalent and making uint32_t as I mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to convert the character to integer

```
uint32_t convertbyte(char *buffer)
{
    uint32_t ret = 0;
    uint8_t i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        ret *= 16;
        if ((buffer[i] >= 'A') && (buffer[i] <= 'F'))
            ret += buffer[i] - 'A' + 10;
        else if ((buffer[i] >= '0') && (buffer[i] <= '9'))
            ret += buffer[i] - '0';
        else
        {
            printf (" Malformed input");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This function can then be called for each 32 bit integer you need to be converted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t convertbyte(char *buffer);

int main(void)
{
    char *buffer = "AABBCCDDEE112233445566";
    uint32_t partitioned, partitioned2;

    partitioned = convertbyte(buffer);
    printf ("%X\n",partitioned);
    
    partitioned2 = convertbyte(buffer+8);
    printf ("%X\n",partitioned2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

> AABBCCDD
>
> EE112233

Comment: `ret += buffer[i] - 'A' + 10;`?  The question did not specify that the input is ASCII.

Comment: From comments above " buffer has series of characters in it as 12345678aa64000101681fa1ed19f39d41e"

Comment: Raje , yes , the buffer has series of characters stored in it. Note: The binary file is converted to hex file and used.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje That's not ASCII.  You can't assume that the characters `A`-`F` are represented by consecutive integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below functions to convert a string of hex representation to 32 bit(same as uint32_t) hex value.

```
int char2hex(char ch)
{
    int value = -1;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '0' : value = 0;
        break;
        case '1' : value = 1;
        break;
        case '2' : value = 2;
        break;
        case '3' : value = 3;
        break;
        case '4' : value = 4;
        break;
        case '5' : value = 5;
        break;
        case '6' : value = 6;
        break;
        case '7' : value = 7;
        break;
        case '8' : value = 8;
        break;
        case '9' : value = 9;
        break;
        case 'A' : 
        case 'a' : value = 10;
        break;
        case 'B' :
        case 'b' : value = 11;
        break;
        case 'C' :
        case 'c' : value = 12;
        break;
        case 'D' :
        case 'd' : value = 13;
        break;
        case 'E' :
        case 'e' : value = 14;
        break;
        case 'F' : 
        case 'f' :value = 15;
        break;
    }
    return value;
}

long str2longhex(char * str){
    int nibble = 0;
    long hex_value = 0;
    for(unsigned int str_i = 0; str_i < 8; str_i++){
#if 1 //Change the 1 to 0 if you want to reverse the endianess
        nibble = char2hex(str[str_i]);
#else
        nibble = char2hex(str[7-str_i]);
#endif        
        if(nibble < 0){
            //Not a hex representation.
            return -1;
        }
        hex_value = ((hex_value<<4)&0xFF) | nibble;
    }
    return hex_value;
}


int main()
{
    char * buffer = "AABBCCDDEE112233445566";
    long value = 0;
    unsigned int buffer_i = 0; 
    while(buffer_i+8 <= strlen(buffer))
    {
        value = str2longhex(&buffer[buffer_i]);
        printf("partitioned_buffer:0x%08lX\n",value);
        buffer_i += 8;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Usually in hex files(if you meant files with .hex) data is stored from lowest memory location to highest that is if the text file contains "AABBCCDD" the corresponding hex value will be 0xDDCCBBAA. Don't know about the representation in your file but do check it.